# Peach sorbet is not setting at all and the mix is having a jelly texture when popped into the freezer

Tags: sugar, ice-cream, gelatin, sorbet, glucose-syrup

I am doing a peach sorbet following pierre herme recipe which literally said:

- 580g of peach puree
- 74g sugar
- 104g water
- 37g of glucose (I've used high quality honey instead)
- 4g of sorbet stabilizer which I couldn't find so I replaced it with 1 gelatin leaf.

I am using Cuisinart ICE 30-BC ice cream machine. I've used it once when I made vanilla ice cream and it worked great.

What I did is getting water and sugar to boil, remove from the heat, then added the honey and gelatin into the mix and pour it over the puree.

Pop it into the fridge at 4 degree Celsius for a night, and already putting the ice cream machin churning into freezer for 24 hours.

The sorbet didn't set at all. It has `confit` texture which is between a `jelly` and `sauce` textures.

To test if the mix will freeze without the machine, I moved it to the freezer at 14 degree celsius and woke up this morning to check it and it was like a jelly texture and it was not an ice block at all.

Did I add lots of sugar ? Or the gelatin leaf was useless and not the correct substitute ? But 1 leaf is 2g and 2g for 580g of liquid + 104 water is not too much at all.

Comment: What did you use as "peach puree" - did you put fresh peaches through a blender, or did you buy a can of prepared product? Also, did you remove the sugar syrup from the hob immediatelly after it started boiling, or did you keep it some time to thicken?

Comment: I made my own peach puree by boiling peach until soft. Drain it, peel it, cut it and blend it. And yes I removed the syrup directly upon boiling. @rumtscho

Comment: @rumtscho is this process correct ?

Comment: The gelatin might have been a bit much - you might need to do some experimentation here; but according to Dana Cree in "Hello, My Name Is Ice Cream", Knox powdered gelatin is good as a stabilizer in a concentration of 0.4% (4g / 1tsp per kg).  1tsp of powdered is roughly equivalent to  1 leaf, so looking at your total weight, you are about 25% too high.

Comment: @ChrisMacksey you are totally true.

Comment: but 1 leaf is 2g not 4g

Comment: Powdered gelatin and leaf gelatin are probably not weight equivalent with each other (especially given the usual volume conversions).  I only have numbers for powdered gelatin as an ice cream stabilizer, not leaf.

Comment: So 4g of stabilizer is 4g of powdered gelatin ?

Comment: I don't see anything in your process that jumps out at me as incorrect. If there is a mistake in it, I don't recognize it. By the way, I have never tried gelatine in frozen desserts, and different thickeners/stabilizers are not interchangeable. But I don't know how gelatine should behave in this case. The symptoms you have sound most like too much sugar:water ratio, but the products you list look like there should be enough water, so I'm puzzled.